# I am facing an issue while adding calculated field through Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, calculated-columns

I am trying to add calculated field through Apache POI and I am facing issue when there is only one non-calculated field and rest others are calculated fields I am getting an error while opening excel sheet as below

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBfUi.png)

But when there are more than one non-calculated fields excel sheet doesn't throw any error and calculated field displayed fine.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        createPivotTable();
    }

    private static void createPivotTable() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("1econtent");
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("1e");

            sheet1.setDisplayGridlines(false);
            setCellData(sheet,wb);

            AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:F5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
            CellReference position = new CellReference(0,0);

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet1.createPivotTable(source, position,wb.getSheet("1econtent"));
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);


            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);


            CTCacheFields ctCacheFields = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields();
            CTCacheField ctCacheField = ctCacheFields.addNewCacheField();
            ctCacheField.setName("Field");
            ctCacheField.setFormula("'Actuals' / 'Estimates'");
            ctCacheField.setDatabaseField(false);
            ctCacheFields.setCount(ctCacheFields.sizeOfCacheFieldArray());

            CTPivotField pivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().addNewPivotField();
            pivotField.setDataField(true);
            pivotField.setDragToCol(false);
            pivotField.setDragToPage(false);
            pivotField.setDragToRow(false);
            pivotField.setShowAll(false);
            pivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);

            CTDataFields dataFields;
            if(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields() != null) {
                dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields();
            } else {
                dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewDataFields();
            }
            CTDataField dataField = dataFields.addNewDataField();
            dataField.setName("Calculated Field");
dataField.setFld(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCount()-1);
            dataField.setBaseItem(0);
            dataField.setBaseField(0);
            DataFormat dataformat =  pivotTable.getParentSheet().getWorkbook().createDataFormat();
            short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.0%");
            dataField.setNumFmtId(numFmtId);

            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Output.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet,XSSFWorkbook wb){
        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell11.setCellValue("Names");
        Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
        cell12.setCellValue("Age");
        Cell cell13 = row1.createCell(2);
        cell13.setCellValue("Dept");
        Cell cell14 = row1.createCell(3);
        cell14.setCellValue("Salary");
        Cell cell15 = row1.createCell(4);
        cell15.setCellValue("Actuals");
        Cell cell16 = row1.createCell(5);
        cell16.setCellValue("Estimates");


        Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
        cell21.setCellValue("Adam");
        Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
        cell22.setCellValue(22);
        Cell cell23 = row2.createCell(2);
        cell23.setCellValue("Sales");
        Cell cell24 = row2.createCell(3);
        cell24.setCellValue(10);
        Cell cell25 = row2.createCell(4);
        cell25.setCellValue(12);
        Cell cell26 = row2.createCell(5);
        cell26.setCellValue(60);

        Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
        Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
        cell31.setCellValue("Bran");
        Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
        cell32.setCellValue(24);
        Cell cell33 = row3.createCell(2);
        cell33.setCellValue("Finance");
        Cell cell34 = row3.createCell(3);
        cell34.setCellValue(20);
        Cell cell35 = row3.createCell(4);
        cell35.setCellValue(24);
        Cell cell36 = row3.createCell(5);
        cell36.setCellValue(60);

        Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
        Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
        cell41.setCellValue("Jane");
        Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
        cell42.setCellValue(23);
        Cell cell43 = row4.createCell(2);
        cell43.setCellValue("IT");
        Cell cell44 = row4.createCell(3);
        cell44.setCellValue(30);
        Cell cell45 = row4.createCell(4);
        cell45.setCellValue(30);
        Cell cell46 = row4.createCell(5);
        cell46.setCellValue(60);

        Row row5 = sheet.createRow(4);
        Cell cell211 = row5.createCell(0);
        cell211.setCellValue("Dave");
        Cell cell221 = row5.createCell(1);
        cell221.setCellValue(30);
        Cell cell231 = row5.createCell(2);
        cell231.setCellValue("Sales");
        Cell cell241 = row5.createCell(3);
        cell241.setCellValue(50);
        Cell cell251 = row5.createCell(4);
        cell251.setCellValue(6);
        Cell cell261 = row5.createCell(5);
        cell261.setCellValue(60);

    }
```

There is no error when I add one or more column labels. Could someone please help me with this.

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM3Nq.png)

Expected output is only one non-calculated column and a calculated column as below.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbArU.png)

Comment: Have you forgotten to close the workbook instance (`wb.close()`)? Your `FileOutputStream` is closed automatically, but the workbook won't.

Comment: @deHaar try with resources would handle the closing part, still tried closing it. didn't work

Comment: The reason I wrote this is my own experience with apache poi creating unreadable workbooks. I ended up not using a `try` with resources because of several things:. `try` with resources does not `flush()` the `FileOutputStream`. I always use a regular `try`-`catch` and the following methods in exactly that order: `workbook.write(fileOutputStream)`, `fileOutputStream.flush()`, `fileOutputStream.close()` and `workbook.close()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an element `colFields` in pivot table definition which needs at least one `field` if there are multiple data fields as column fields. But `apache poi` does not add that field if only one column label is set because it is not needed if only one column field is present.

But since you low level adds a data field as column field it then lacks that  `colFields` field. That's why the error while opening the file in `Excel`.

If multiple column labels are set then `apache poi` adds that `colFields` field. That's why it works then.

So add following to your code after your low level creating the data field:

```
...
   // at least one field in colFields is needed if there are multiple data fields
   CTColFields colFields;
   if(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields() != null) {
    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields();
   } else {
    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields();
   }
   CTField field;
   if (colFields.getFieldList().size() == 0) {
    field = colFields.addNewField();
    field.setX(-2);
   }
...
```

This adds a new `colFields` element if not already present. And it adds that `field` element there, if not already present.

The complete example again:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

class CreatePivotTableCalculatedFields {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  createPivotTable();
 }

 private static void createPivotTable() throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Output.xlsx")) {

   XSSFSheet dataSheet = wb.createSheet("1econtent");
   XSSFSheet pivotSheet = wb.createSheet("1e");

   setCellData(dataSheet, wb);

   AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:F5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   CellReference position = new CellReference(0,0);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, position,wb.getSheet("1econtent"));
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);

   pivotSheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);

   wb.setSelectedTab(1);
   wb.setActiveSheet(1);

   // customize pivot table
   CTCacheFields ctCacheFields = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields();
   CTCacheField ctCacheField = ctCacheFields.addNewCacheField();
   ctCacheField.setName("Field");
   ctCacheField.setFormula("'Actuals' / 'Estimates'");
   ctCacheField.setDatabaseField(false);
   ctCacheFields.setCount(ctCacheFields.sizeOfCacheFieldArray());

   CTPivotField pivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().addNewPivotField();
   pivotField.setDataField(true);
   pivotField.setDragToCol(false);
   pivotField.setDragToPage(false);
   pivotField.setDragToRow(false);
   pivotField.setShowAll(false);
   pivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);

   CTDataFields dataFields;
   if(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields() != null) {
    dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields();
   } else {
    dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewDataFields();
   }
   CTDataField dataField = dataFields.addNewDataField();
   dataField.setName("Calculated Field");
   dataField.setFld(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCount()-1);
   dataField.setBaseItem(0);
   dataField.setBaseField(0);
   DataFormat dataformat =  pivotTable.getParentSheet().getWorkbook().createDataFormat();
   short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.0%");
   dataField.setNumFmtId(numFmtId);

   // at least one field in colFields is needed if there are multiple data fields
   CTColFields colFields;
   if(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields() != null) {
    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields();
   } else {
    colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields();
   }
   CTField field;
   if (colFields.getFieldList().size() == 0) {
    field = colFields.addNewField();
    field.setX(-2);
   }

   wb.write(fileOut);
  }
 }

 public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFWorkbook wb){
  Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
   new Object[] {"Names", "Age", "Dept", "Salary", "Actuals", "Estimates"},
   new Object[] {"Adam", 22d, "Sales", 10d, 12d, 60d},
   new Object[] {"Bran", 24d, "Finance", 20d, 24d, 60d},
   new Object[] {"Jane", 23d, "IT", 30d, 30d, 60d},
   new Object[] {"Dave", 30d, "Sales", 50d, 6d, 60d}
  };

  XSSFRow row;
  XSSFCell cell;
  for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0 ; c < data[r].length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (data[r][c] instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
    } else if (data[r][c] instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
    }
   }
  }
 } 
}
```